# How to load kml files into osgEarth using .earth file?

Tags: gis, google-earth, openscenegraph

I want to simply show some kml files with osgearth_viewer.exe.

I've read the osgEarth documentation and get nothing about how to load a lot of KML files by using .earth file with osgearth_viewer.exe.

I know how to load one kml file using comand line parameter --kml , but I wanna to show all kml files once.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to recognize your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example here: 
http://code.metager.de/source/xref/osgearth/src/applications/osgearth_kml/osgearth_kml.cpp#63

Shows pretty clearly how you do it. Just do the

```
        osg::Node* kml = osgDB::readNodeFile( kmlFile, options.get() );
        if ( kml )
            root->addChild( kml );
```

steps as many times as you want for as many KML files as you want.

Comment: OK,at last I found that cannot load more than one kml file using comand line, and I wrote a Qt-OSGEarth frame application